# TAB separation for strings in write.csv

Tags: r, csv

I have a dataset that is comma separated (.csv file) and the strings are delimited with TAB. The read command looks like this:

```
read.csv("R_input.csv", sep = ",", quote = "\t")
```

quote = "\t" because there are cases where in columns where a double quote is used instead of a single one and it screws everything up.

How can i write a .csv file with string quote that is TAB and not a double or single quote (" or ')?
NOTE: It boggles my mind that i can import something, but i can't return it in the same format...

Comment: `qmethod = "escape" ` option (or one of the other quote method options) may be of use in your write.csv command.

Comment: @RyanMorton Sadly, it didn't work. I would have been very surprised if it did.

Comment: Maybe you can give us an actual example of the output you're getting versus the output you expect.  Many of us would test our suggestions for you prior to giving them, but you haven't provided a reproducible example.

Comment: @RyanMorton I'd love to upload the data set, but i don't think i can...

Comment: Please follow this link:

https://pastebin.com/CM9GG5Q2

This is how the data looks.